# Dynamically building a Merkle tree for unkown size

Tags: hash-tree

Assuming a $k$-ary Merkle tree:

If the length of a file is known, based on a fixed chunk size, one could calculate the number of chunks and thus the depth of the tree. Then, based on $k$, the chunk index and the depth, one can parallelize the construction of the Merkle tree.

But if the file size is not known, i.e., the input is a stream, and we are reading the input until EOF, what could be an efficient procedure to build up the $k$-ary Merkle tree, assuming as usual that leaf nodes contain the chunk hash, while branch nodes contain the hashes of their children?

Comment: One could first read the input until EOF, then out of this determine the number of chunks and thus build the tree the same way as described in the question. I wonder if one can just read chunks and then send them to a routine in parallel and build the tree as we go...

Comment: I'd create a scheme with a fixed block and size (say, 4KiB) and $k$ value, say 16 minimum (to allow 16 worker-threads to calculate the values). You can always create a new root (i.e. make the tree deeper) when you need more space. In other words, I would make the Merkle tree depth a function of the size. But that's just my idea / opinion.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it took me some time to understand what you mean. But I think your basic proposal is what I will need. Thanks. (You can post it as an answer if you like, I didn't post any code either so I may accept your generic idea, but I'll give myself some time)

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple to achieve. I'll just show you what you have to compute as each chunk $c_1, c_2, c_3, \ldots$ comes in.

You start empty.

You get $c_1$, hash it as $h_1$, and obtain your Merkle root.
If no more chunks come in, you are done.

```
    h_1
     |
    c_1
```

Otherwise, you get $c_2$, hash it as $h_2$.
You put it next to $h_1$. Now you have two leaves, hash them and get their parent hash $r_{1,2}$:

```
     r_{1,2}
    /      \
 h_1       h_2
  |         |
 c_1       c_2
```

Maybe you are done now? If not.
You get $c_3$.
Now you have a **forest**.

```
     r_{1,2}
    /      \
 h_1       h_2     h_3
  |         |       |
 c_1       c_2     c_3
```

If you are done, you can let your final digest be the hash of all the roots in this forest.

If not, you get $c_4$.
Now, you can start **merging** things in your forest, by hashing.

```
            r_{1,4}
        /             \
     r_{1,2}        r_{3,4}
    /      \        /     \
 h_1       h_2     h_3   h_4
  |         |       |     |
 c_1       c_2     c_3   c_4
```

By now, you get the picture?

- You always append new chunks to the right of your forest.
- Whenever you have two subtrees of the same size (i.e., same # of leaves), you merge them by Merkle hashing their roots together
- Your file's final digest will be the hash of all roots in your forest

**$O(1)$ digest.** Because you always hash the roots together into a single digest at the end, this approach gives you a constant-sized digest, just like a Merkle tree.

**Computationally-optimized.** This forest-based approach will minimize the # of hashes you compute.

**Why forest?** You could also maintain a tree instead of a forest over all chunks received so far, but that will unnecessarily recompute a lot of hashes as new chunks get added "under the tree."

**Number of trees?** For $n$ chunks, you will not have more than $\log_2{n}$ trees in your forest.

**Space-complexity optimization:** Furthermore, you could actually implement this without keeping track of all the trees; just of their roots!